# Obtain more precise build time

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a possibility to get more precise execution time when I run `<Ctrl+B>` program in ***Sublime text 3***?

By default the precision is 1 digit after comma. But while learning I use tiny pieces of code and can not tell if my implementation is good in terms of complexity and thus speed.

[image: my image]

P.S. I know there are the ways to measure execution time using some modules. Maybe there are ones that I can use in a fast and convenient way while coding (so there's no need to force this verbose info into `<Ctrl+B>` result screen)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by modifying the `exec.py` file in the `Default` package; this provides the `exec` command which is used by Sublime to execute build systems.

The easiest way to do that is:

1. Install the [OverrideAudit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/OverrideAudit) package if you haven't already
2. Open the Command Palette (`Tools > Command Palette..` or <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+P</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+⌘+P</kbd>) and filter down with `oa:co` to get at `OverrideAudit: Create Override`
3. Choose the package `Default` from the list, and then the file `exec.py`

As mentioned above, this file contains the `exec` command that Sublime uses to execute build systems. The contents of the file will be different depending on the version of Sublime Text that you have installed (3 versus 4), but in either case the change to make is easy.

To determine what version of Sublime you're using, pick `Help: About` from the command palette or from the main menu; the build number displayed in the About dialog will be in the 3000's if you're using ST3 and in the 4000's if you're using ST4.

### If you're using ST3

Navigate to the `finish()` method, and modify the following lines (see instructions below) and save the file:

```py
            if exit_code == 0 or exit_code == None:
                self.append_string(proc,
                    ("[Finished in %.1fs]" % (elapsed)))
            else:
                self.append_string(proc, ("[Finished in %.1fs with exit code %d]\n"
                    % (elapsed, exit_code)))
                self.append_string(proc, self.debug_text)
```

### If you're using ST4

Navigate to the `on_finished()` method and modify the following lines (see instructions below) and save the file:

```py
        if proc.killed:
            self.write("\n[Cancelled]")
        elif not self.quiet:
            elapsed = time.time() - proc.start_time
            if elapsed < 1:
                elapsed_str = "%.0fms" % (elapsed * 1000)
            else:
                elapsed_str = "%.1fs" % (elapsed)
```

In both cases, the ***.1f*** is specifying the precision used. Note that in ST4 the display will count in milliseconds instead of seconds for builds that take less than a second.

Either way, regardless of your build of Sublime changing the `.1f` to something else (e.g. `.5f`) will increase the level of precision you get from the time.

### Potential Caveats

A caveat to doing this is that this overrides the built in `exec` command with your modified version. If Sublime updates the `Default` package to have an enhanced `exec` command (as was done with the switch from ST3 to ST4), your version will keep being used regardless.

The OverrideAudit package will let you know if this happens, to allow you to make sure that you're not missing out on any vital bug fixes or feature enhancements.